# Ngx Teximate and

Tags: css, angular, ng-animate

I am trying to use ngx teximate https://github.com/MurhafSousli/ngx-teximate to add animations to my text. I have managed to use "[enter]" and the animation works properly.

But when I use "[annimation]" and `.play()` (using ViewChild and a #tag) to play the animation the rest of the text is not hidden as the animation plays out like it is on "[enter]".

Do you know why? I ve tried to hide it manually by binding [style.visibility] to a boolean but when I unhide it it shows the whole text together again instead of letting the animation show it.

Is there anything I can do to fix that or is it decided by the library?

I want to make a chain of events/animations and having everything on [enter] makes them all simultaneous.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

I used "[enter]" but also used *ngIf and a toggle to re-initialize the angular component at will, effectively triggering the animation again.